# NULL values in unique constraints

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

I have been asked several times in interviews this question.

Why an unique key allows one null value?

I searched for the answers but I couldn't find one.
Please help me on this

Comment: Relevant https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299229/change-unique-constraint-to-allow-multiple-null-values

Answer (score 4):

- Because Microsoft have implemented UNIQUE constraints to behave like this, apparently.  This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints#Unique) (quote)

> ...UNIQUE constraints allow for the value NULL. However, as with any
>   value participating in a UNIQUE constraint, only one null value is
>   allowed per column ...

Apparently, this is not the behaviour as defined in the [ANSI](http://www.ansi.org) SQL standard documents (as Martin Smith's link suggests).

Other database servers behave differently in this respect.  E.g. PostgreSQL allows you to do this:

```
create table t ( id int unique ) ;

insert into t (id) values (1),(2),(3),(null),(null),(null) ;

-- 6 rows affected
```

See [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6cc0155d72eb5fbafb9d7d104075d554).

When working with Oracle, you can do this (or something similar), too -

```
create table t ( id int unique ) ;

begin
  insert into t (id) values (1);
  insert into t (id) values (2);
  insert into t (id) values (3);
  insert into t (id) values (null);
  insert into t (id) values (null);
  insert into t (id) values (null) ;
end;
/

select * from t;

ID
----
1
2
3
null
null
null
```

Dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=60c5047b8a95ecb9aee459f8442c0285).

Comment: Regarding getting a copy. The 1992 version is on the Internet: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt (maybe not the official one but close enough for me). A much newer version is available here: https://www.wiscorp.com/SQLStandards.html (under "SQL:20nn Working Draft Documents"), along with many other related stuff.